# How to receive notification of deprecated API elements and functions?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-debug, deprecation

There is some way to get notifications when deprecated API elements are used in WordPress. How is it done? Put WordPress in debug mode (which also shows all other types of errors) or is there another method that shows only API related errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install the [Log Deprecated Notices](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/log-deprecated-notices/) plugin.